# Why do programs like Skype not require you to open ports?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, udp, portforwarding

I'm currently working on a messaging program in java, and I planned on using UDP to send messages from the user to a central server, and I planned on using possibly TCP for messages from the server going back to the user. My main question is, how can I achieve this without requiring the client to port forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply, the client has to establish the TCP connection to the server, even if the primary (indeed if not *only*) data flow is in the opposite direction.

Comment: I didn't realize I could have the traffic go in the opposite direction! I thought TCP required both to create a connection, due to the nature of TCP (3 way handshake). Thanks for clearing this up for me!

Comment: Any firewalls / NATs in the path will let the three way handshake complete (assuming the outbound traffic is permitted) otherwise no TCP connection would ever work.

Answer (score 2):

P2P clients like skype use subtle tricks to connect peers behind firewalls. The different techniques used are outlined here:
http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747197.html

Answer (score 1):

Programs like skype either use a common port that is open (port 80) or put a rule in the firewall to allow another port to communicate.  Additionally a program can open ports above 1024 without adminisrative permissions although depending on the type of connection it may need to set up UPnP or keep an active channel to a server open. [image: Windows Firewall]

Comment: And how exactly are multiple programs able to share the same port, yet, when I accidentally leave an instance of my server running, I get an exception due to the port already being in use?

Comment: When a program opens a port it can set the port to be nonexclusive if it wants to share that port.  The default is usually to be exclusive so that's why you would get that error.